# Displaying the contents of a txt file on a web server

Tags: javascript, php, html, flask, xmlhttprequest

I have a webpage of a server I need to add additional functionality to. Namely I would like to display on the webpage the contents of a txt file saved on the server. Im not totally familiar with the syntax which is giving me trouble but it looks to be using flask along with html & javascript functions to populate the page.

I have tried using an xmlhttp request without luck.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>Rigidity Analysis</h4>
                    <pre class="experimentRecord" onload="loadXMLDoc()" >{{ "test" }}</pre>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function loadXMLDoc() {
                  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                      this.responseText;
                    }
                  };
                  xhttp.open("GET", '../hello.txt', true);
                  xhttp.send();
                }

                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is how I am using a php request.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>Rigidity Analysis</h4>
                      <iframe src="test.php"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Which links to a php file:

```
<?php
  echo readfile("../hello.txt");
?>
```

[Here is the full html file with the portion I am trying to add on line 50.](https://gist.github.com/Silverfin13/9dcbf8256be4f3b4562307c33db81924) And the output on the server.

[image: and a screenshot of the output]

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? Can you access the file by using the browser?

Comment: @Luca Tere are of course errors when testing the file outside the server without its associated files, but the console is clean when run on the server.

Comment: So, can you access the file from the browser?

Comment: @Luca yes, however it wont display the txt contents. It should appear under Rigidity Analysis here: http://rmutant2.cs.wwu.edu/results?uid=A6BVEZNE

Comment: Updated my answer. You can embed `php` into an `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `readfile`?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

```
<?php
echo readfile("../hello.txt");
?>
```

P.S.: You are trying to run `php` code in a `html` file. That won't work. Simply change `results.html` to `results.php`.

UPDATE:

Alternatively, create another file `txt.php`:

```
<?php
  echo readfile("../hello.txt");
?>
```

And then in your `results.html` embed it like this:

```
<iframe src="test.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well perhaps I am not embedding the php correctly? I will update.

Comment: @Silverfin You are trying to run `php` in a `html` file. Change the file to `results.php` otherwise your embedded code won't run.

Comment: looks like the file is required to be an html file to work alongside the other functions.

Comment: @Silverfin Why? As far as I can see it contains only html and javascript? That should just be fine if you change the extension. Anyway, it won't work as long as it's a html file.

Comment: @ fishmong3r Thanks, I see how it should work. i've somehow managed to create a page not found within an iFrame now however.

Comment: @Silverfin are `test.php` and `results.html` in the same folder?

Comment: yes, ive updated to how I have written them in the files.

Comment: It should just work as you have it in your Q. Please double check file names, locations, extension.

Comment: Ive run it off the server with a test script, looks like the iframe is trying to download the php file itself.

Comment: Php is running on server side. If your php file is not placed on a server which has php installed, then it won't be translated. For e.g. you can't open a local php file in your browser on your desktop because it's not running client-side like html or javascript.